# ASP.NET Core 6 cannot resolve database name when running in docker container (in WSL2)

Tags: postgresql, docker, dns, wsl-2, asp.net-core-6.0

I am dockerizing an ASP.NET Core 6 application step by step as follows:

- I have set up WSL2 in Windows 10 and installed Racher Desktop. This allows running docker commands as if run in the WSL2 guest
- I have run a Postgresql container and it is accessible to both host (Windows) pgAdmin and for the ASP.NET Core when run from Visual Studio:

```
docker run -d -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -p 5433:5432 postgres
```

(port 5432 was hijacked by some service before installing the Postgres and I had to use another port).

When running from Visual Studio, the application uses the following connection string:

```
Host=localhost:5433; Database=foo-next; Username=postgres; Password=postgres; Timeout=300; CommandTimeout=300
```

I have created a Dockerfile and a docker image for the application. When running I receive the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name does not resolve
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, ValueStopwatch stopwatch)
   at System.Net.Dns.<>c.<GetHostEntryOrAddressesCoreAsync>b__33_0(Object s, ValueStopwatch stopwatch)
   at System.Net.Dns.<>c__DisplayClass39_0`1.<RunAsync>b__0(Task <p0>, Object <p1>)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.ExecuteWithTimeout[TResult](Func`2 func, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.WithCancellation[T](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|191_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.UnpooledConnectorSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I interpret this as the application not being able to resolve `postgres` hostname. I have checked if Postgres containers and the .NET Core one run in the same network and they seem they do, but some attributes are missing for my app network metadata:

Wehn running in the container, the application uses the following connection string:

```
Host=postgres:5433; Database=foo-next-docker; Username=postgres; Password=postgres; Timeout=300; CommandTimeout=300
```

```
docker inspect postgres -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"
{"bridge":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"343ece236719b94d53df0afe1ab0d405a19102002f67ea60a1914016d4e4f96b","EndpointID":"9c3740b300caaf50f86731f00530dce62b386b56ccc2fe3da96c4cb677dcb42d","Gateway":"172.17.0.1","IPAddress":"172.17.0.3","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:11:00:03","DriverOpts":null}}

docker inspect foonextapp -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"
{"bridge":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"343ece236719b94d53df0afe1ab0d405a19102002f67ea60a1914016d4e4f96b","EndpointID":"","Gateway":"","IPAddress":"","IPPrefixLen":0,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"","DriverOpts":null}}
```

The same result I get when explicitly running the container attached to the `bridge` network:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 --name fooapp fooapp --network=bridge
```

Not sure if it provides more information, but the whole docker network list is the following:

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME       DRIVER    SCOPE
343ece236719   bridge     bridge    local
df0c354db7cf   host       host      local
6efb481fc02b   minikube   bridge    local
23bdb658109a   none       null      local
```

Any suggestions about what to try next in order to make the app running in local container resolve the database container name?

Note: all commands were run in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a network-alias, because [a container’s hostname defaults to be the container’s ID](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#ip-address-and-hostname).

In PowerShell:

```
docker network create app
```

```
docker run -dp 5433:5432 `
    -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data `
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres `
    --network app --network-alias postgres `
    postgres
```

```
docker run -dp 8080:80 --network app fooapp
```

Comment: +1. It worked. For the newbies like me, it is important to know that only user networks can be used like this: `docker network create app`.

Comment: Forgot to mention, but I guess that using docker-compose prevents this issue I faced if properly defining the networks.

Comment: @Alexei-checkCodidact, you can choose not to define any networks in docker-compose and use service names as hostnames

Comment: Yes, I have worked with docker support in Visual Studio and everything worked like a charm with docker-compose. I thought to have a quick and dirty solution using docker only, but I was wrong that it would be quicker. Anyway, I have learned something new about docker networks. 10x.